# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fiats' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I want to show the data coming from the API as frontend in the angular project I made, but I'm getting an error .. I searched the internet a lot, but I couldn't get the results I wanted. I would be glad you can help with this.

**Error**

```
vendor.js:16522 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fiats' of undefined
    at FiatsComponent_Template (main.js:219)
    at executeTemplate (vendor.js:19621)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:19490)
    at refreshComponent (vendor.js:20637)
    at refreshChildComponents (vendor.js:19296)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:19540)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (vendor.js:20591)
    at refreshView (vendor.js:19514)
    at refreshComponent (vendor.js:20637)
    at refreshChildComponents (vendor.js:19296)
```

**API Service**

```
const API_URL = 'https://api.bitpanda.com/v1/masterdata';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getDatafromApi() {
    return this.http.get<Attributes[]>(API_URL);
  }
}
```

**fiats.compontent.ts**

```
export class FiatsComponent implements OnInit {
  apiData: Attributes[];
  apiDataA: Attributes;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDatafromAPI();
    console.log(' ', this.getDatafromAPI()); //undefined
  }

  getDatafromAPI() {
    this.apiService.getDatafromApi().subscribe((data) => {
      this.apiData = data;
      console.log(' ', data); ////data
    });
  }
}
```

**fiats.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let A of apiDataA.fiats">
  <div *ngFor="let b of A.attributes">
    <p>{{ b.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time your template renders `apiDataA` is undefined. The data you retrieve from your api returns later.

You can solve this easily with an enclosing container around your *ngFor loop:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="apiDataA">
...
</ng-container>
```

You could also look into using Angulars [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting the returned data to apiData instead of apiDataA. Your data is also in a nested array and you are just missing a level.

```
  getDatafromAPI() {
    this.apiService.getDatafromApi().subscribe((data) => {
      this.apiDataA = data;
      console.log(' ', data); ////data
    });
 }

<ng-container *ngIf="apiDataA">
  <div *ngFor="let A of apiDataA.attributes">
    <div *ngFor="let b of A.fiats">
      <p>{{ b.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: here is the api url: https://api.bitpanda.com/v1/masterdata
and i must to show the all fiats

Comment: @mes It's a nested array - you are missing a level. I've updated my answer

Comment: I did what you said, but still no change, the error came back.
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fiats' of undefined

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the working code. Consider updating the conditional statement on the container to this: `<ng-container *ngIf="apiDataA?.attributes">`